# C++, glut, OpenGL "resize window" event?

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glut

I use OpenGL 3.3. In my app, I set the mouse cursor in the center of the window(I pass the size of window to the constructor of "Camera" class), but when I resize the window(like full screen) I have the cursor somewhere in the left part. So, I want to pass new size to avoid such thing. How can i do this? Maybe exists some kind of "resize" event in glut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [glutReshapeFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node48.html#SECTION00083000000000000000). You pass it a pointer to a function that accepts a width and a height. Then that function will be called whenever the window is reshaped.

Example:

```
void yourReshapeCallback(int w, int h) {
  // set cursor
}
...
// set reshape callback for current window
glutReshapeFunc(yourReshapeCallback);
```